# Prove that $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)^2+\frac{1}{4}(a+b)\ge a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}$

Tags: inequality

How to prove
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}(a+b)^2+\frac{1}{4}(a+b)\ge a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}\ ,where \   a,b\ge 0  
\end{equation*}
I applied AM-GM inequality but obtained only
\begin{equation*}
\frac{3}{2}(a+b)\ge a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}+1 
\end{equation*}
which is not true for, example, $a=0, \ b=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Hint: $a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{ab}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

Comment: @danimal yes I can see it now, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From first principles:

$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \geq 0$$
$$x+y-2\sqrt{xy} \geq 0$$
$$\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$$

And:

$$(\sqrt{x}-\frac12)^2 \geq 0$$
$$x+\frac14-\sqrt{x} \geq 0$$
$$\sqrt{x} \leq x + \frac14$$

Given that:
$$\begin{split}
a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a} &= \sqrt{ab}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}) \\
&\leq\frac{a+b}2(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}) \\
&\leq\frac{a+b}2(a+b+\frac12) \\
&=\frac12(a+b)^2+\frac14(a+b)
\end{split}$$
$$$$